# Break through TCP/IP port exhaution (on Windows)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, port, internet

I'm searching for a setup where one Windows with one ethernet card is able to handle more then 65k open IPv4 TCP connections -- yes, it's not possible per default by the specification.

I've found a nice tutorial how to setup [How to tune the TCP/IP stack for high volume of web requests](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?Topic=How-to-tune-the-TCP/IP-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests) Windows and Linux regarding maximum usable ports.

My idea would be to setup multiple IP address per ethernet controller (MAC address) and let the DNS server round robin over [CNAME Resource Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).

The server application running on the Windows machine would bind to multiple IP addresses attached to the same MAC address (ethernet controller).

The clients would be redirected to different IP address by DNS server served by the same server.

Where is defined -- official Microsoft documentation in printed or online appreciated -- how many IP addresses can be set per ethernet controler? (Try it out is not reliable)

Are there any other ideas how to solve the limitations without using additional infrastructural changes e.g. visualization or additional nic?

Comment: Covers the same ground as ["Is an Apache use TCP port on each connection?"](http://serverfault.com/questions/279010/).

Comment: You've made it rather difficult to help you. Instead of providing detailed information about your *actual* problem, you've written a lengthy text about how you are going to try and solve a non-existing issue. I'd recommend reading http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for some improvements.

Comment: Not really. I would like to know how to setup the operating system in order to allow more then the theoretical limit for port numbers per IP address.

Comment: I'm completely confused by your question and your comments to the answer that syneticon-dj posted. Is your problem on the client side or the server side? If it's on the server side then you're misunderstanding things as syneticon-dj has stated. From the listener (server) perspective, incoming connections are only limited to what that particular server can support in terms of resources used per connection. If the server has enough memory and CPU it could support millions of incoming connections per listener port (maybe not millions, but a heck of a lot).

Comment: Sorry for that. I confirm with you that a server is able to respond to a bunch of connections but only if the socket connection is closed. Imagine a situation where the server and client does not close the connection. This is the case e.g. for long HTTP requests.

Comment: 65 thousand ACTIVE http sessions on a single web server? Are you joking?

Comment: Why not? If most of them are silent it should not be an issue regarding the network throughput but with memory usage. The point is how to achieve that? What possibilities the IP stack on Windows is able to handle.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have misunderstood the limitation. If you are running a server with listening sockets, you are not affected by the port limit. The service just listens on one or several ports (e.g. port 80 for a web server) and does not "use up" more than that.

Only with the service's clients the picture is different. They need to "reserve" a port for each connection request to serve as the connection's endpoint. Usually you will not run out of ports unless the client is creating a huge number of connections for some reason or is rotating them very fast so the system runs out of ports before TIME_WAIT timers expire.

> One client opens and hold multiple TCP connections but there are multiple 1000 workstations running this client in my scenario

You are not seeing port exhaustion then. If you are experiencing problems, it will be due to something else. There is a thing like the memory limit for the non-paged-pool which would mainly apply for 32-bit systems and effectively limit the number of connections at around 44.000 - see section 4.8 of the [Winsock FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/advanced.html) for details. You might be hitting a number of other limits too. This [smallvoid.com article](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html) explains some of them.

Comment: The client establish the initial connection over the well known port. Further data exchange is done over different ports but the socket is not closed in order to be able to exchange further data -- e.g. the same for AJAX application with long HTTP requests.

For a big number of clients with long HTTP requests you run into these scenario where "all" port are in use.

Comment: You **never** run into port exhaustion with listeners after they are opened. On the server side, client connections do not "use up" any ports. You **may** run into port exhaustion with client connections, but that is unlikely and not what you describe.

Comment: Let me correct. Yes I've a scenario where I'm running out of port for client connections -- sorry for the incorrect description.

The clients do not close their socket connections to the server.

I'm looking now for a setup where I'm able to serve more then 65k open port connections on one server without visualization or further nic.

Comment: So a single client is opening tens of thousands of connections?

Comment: One client opens and hold multiple TCP connections but there are multiple 1000 workstations running this client in my scenario.

Comment: It's not port exhaustion then. I've updated the answer with some additional comments.

Comment: You are right. From the theoretical point of view there are free ports but the operating systems stack does not allow more to use -- it does not matter why.

What is the strategy to solve this issue on Windows is the key question.

If the non-paged-pool is used for the overall IP stack on windows it would not be possible to apply further IP addresses to overcome the problem. Is it right?

Comment: Right. But even the paged pool exhaustion is a speculative guess. As you hardly tell us anything about your environment and the exact symptoms you are suffering, there is nothing anyone can do but speculate.

Comment: I know this has been covered in another Question before, I can't find it yet. TCP keeps track of connections on the 4 tupple. That's Source IP, Source Port, Destination IP, Destination Port. Assuming your server has 1 IP, and your service only uses 1 Port, each Client can use 1IP and ~50k Ports. Now assuming about one tenth the IPs on the Internet could be clients (~400M) that gives us about 20 Trillion reasonable 4 Tupples. A more immediate problems is that Windows takes ~2KB of RAM to keep track of each connection. The Practical limit (RAM) will run out way before the Theoretical one.

Comment: @syneticon Windows hasn't used Winsock since the Win95/NT3&4 days. Unless he's running an ancient version of Windows those limits don't apply.

Comment: All the socket-related WSA* functions "use winsock" - it's just that nowdays winsock is part of the operating system and not an add-on-install any more.